# Can I shorten the process of adding multiple variables in Python?

Tags: python, loops, variables, indexing

I have a list and from that list every variable uses one index for a value. Example:

```
val = [2, 4, 8, 6]

var1 = val[0]
var2 = val[1]
var3 = val[2]
var4 = val[3]
```

Can I put this into a loop somehow? Because I have 20 values so it is long to write 20 variables.

P.S of course, the values from added variables must be usable. And the format I'm using those variables looks like this:

```
D = {u'label1': var1, u'label2: var2...}
```

Comment: What's the point? What are you trying to achieve? Why using `val[i]` isn't good enough?

Comment: Im using the values for a bar chart. And I have a bar for every month not exactly 20 but 12. And that list called val is reading values from a text file. So when you change the value in the txt file, the bar chart changes. Im doing this all for practice since Im a begginer :)

Answer (score 1):

For your specific issue you could use your dict directly from the list

```
D = {u'label0' : var[0], u'label1' : val[1],...}
```

and create the dict as

```
D = dict(("var{}".format(i),v) for i,v in enumerate(val))
```

Then, you refer to it as `values["var1"]` for example, where you can put as key the name you like, `label_` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try it,

```
label_dict = {}
for i in range(len(val)):
    label_dict['label' + str(i+1)] = val[i]
```